# How to set padding between mat-icon and button title

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

```html
<button mat-raised-button color="warn">
     <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
     Remove Driver
</button>
```

How to add padding in between `mat-icon` and `button` title?

I want to keep the button title in the middle of the button and keep the icon in the left corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a padding to your button text instead of the icon.

Add a class for the button text in the template.

```html
<button mat-raised-button color="warn">
    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    <span class="button-text">Remove Driver</span>
</button>
```

Then define `button-text` in the CSS.

```js
.button-text {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 74px; /* Add 24px to align the text in the center since the icon's width is 24px */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to add `span` tag for that under button title

```
<button mat-raised-button color="warn">
     <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
     <span class="button-title">Remove Driver</span>
</button>
```

Then just add this `.button-title` in your CSS file for Styling

```
.button-title{
    padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px; 
}
```

This is Example You Can edit or preview Code [Here on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vep3fb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: So what's different in your answer from @nash11's answer?

Comment: I didn't saw any changes yet in your answer.

Comment: Brother don't get offended, my only concern is no point to add same content answer that already give on the same question. Hope you understand.